# Dynamically added columns in Radgrid headers text gets clears on psotback

Tags: telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a `Radgrid` with some columns which are pre-defined in `aspx template` and some which are needed to dynamically add code based on some control events.

Now after Post-back or sorting in grid, the header text of the dynamically added columns gets cleared. And sometimes the values also get cleared. If I bind those columns again on postback then previous column shows `system.row` values and the new columns gets appended into existing layout.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/defining-structure/creating-a-radgrid-programmatically) from Telerik, the dynamically created columns need to be added in the Init event.

> Creating columns in the Page_Load event handler does not work for template columns. For the controls inside a template to persist their ViewState , the grid must be generated completely in the code-behind using the Page_Init event (see below). That way, template controls are instantiated before the LoadViewState event of the page.

You can try moving the adding of the columns in the Page_Init event. If all the columns that you are adding are template columns, this could definitely fix the issues you are having.

I hope this fix can resolve your problem.